# Tabbing to next field in Eclipse JFace dialog when '.' pressed

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have an Eclipse JFace `Dialog` with several `Text` fields in it.  When the user presses the `.` key in a text field, I want it to behave as though the tab key had been pressed and focus sent to the next text field and the `.` thrown away (think entering an IP address).

How is this best implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want. Basically it adds `KeyListener` and `FocusListener` to the `Text` widgets and circles through them when `.` is pressed:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        /* These are the text fields */
        final Text textOne = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        final Text textTwo = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        final Text textThree = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

        /* Save them in an arraylist */
        final ArrayList<Text> textFields = new ArrayList<Text>();
        textFields.add(textOne);
        textFields.add(textTwo);
        textFields.add(textThree);

        /* save their position as well (not optimal, you can think of an easier method) */
        final HashMap<Text, Integer> textFieldsMapping = new HashMap<Text, Integer>();
        textFieldsMapping.put(textOne, 0);
        textFieldsMapping.put(textTwo, 1);
        textFieldsMapping.put(textThree, 2);

        /* Define keylistener which takes care of using . as tab */
        KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                /* if '.' pressed */
                if(arg0.character == '.')
                {
                    /* ignore this action */
                    arg0.doit = false;

                    /* get next text field */
                    Text next = textFields.get(counter);

                    /* force focus on this text field */
                    next.setFocus();
                    next.forceFocus();
                }
            }
        };

        /* Define focuslistener which sets current position */
        FocusListener focusListener = new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                /* get current text field */
                Text current = (Text)arg0.getSource();

                /* get current position */
                int currentPosition = textFieldsMapping.get(current);

                /* set counter to next text field */
                counter = (currentPosition + 1) % textFields.size();
            }
        };

        /* add keylistener to text fields */
        textOne.addKeyListener(keyListener);
        textTwo.addKeyListener(keyListener);
        textThree.addKeyListener(keyListener);

        /* add focuslistener to text fields */
        textOne.addFocusListener(focusListener);
        textTwo.addFocusListener(focusListener);
        textThree.addFocusListener(focusListener);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was originally trying to find a way to invoke the same process that takes place when the tab key is pressed, but got nowhere with that approach.  It seems that setting focus directly to the next control is the way to go.  Are you aware of a way to invoke the tab logic?
 
Since I posted, I found the VerifyListener class.  By adding a verify listener to a control, I can intercept the '.' event and set focus to the next field.